# What is the format of xml string(configuration properties) to be passed as an request to oozie scheduler?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oozie

HTTP 400 Bad request when submitting a job to oozie scheduler. The job is not getting submitted due to http request format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>nameNode</name>
    <value>hdfs://e2e-36-167.e2enetworks.net.in:8020</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>jobTracker</name>
    <value>e2e-36-171.e2enetworks.net.in:8050</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>queueName</name>
    <value>default</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark</name>
    <value>spark2</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark.exclusion</name>
    <value>oozie/jackson</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>user.name</name>
    <value>oozie</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.coord.application.path</name>
    <value>hdfs://e2e-36-167.e2enetworks.net.in:8020/spark-computation/coordinator.xml</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.user.name</name>
    <value>oozie</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

I think there are some format issues in the above request because of which it is throwing bad request 400 error

Comment: Can you please add the entire http request you are using (using curl for example) ?

Comment: String url = "http://e2e-36-171.e2enetworks.net.in:11000/oozie/v1/jobs";

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
  
  HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(postBody, headers);
  System.out.println("debug 1");
  ResponseEntity<String> schedulerResponse = new RestTemplate().postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
  
  
  System.out.println("debug 2");

  return (schedulerResponse != null) ? schedulerResponse.getBody() : null;